# WooCommerce Custom Attribute being indexed but shows no results

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, algolia

We're running WordPress 4.7, WooCommerce 2.6.9 and the Algolia 1.6.0.

We've got 7 indexes setup:

```
Searchable posts [searchable_posts]
Posts [posts_post]
Pages [posts_page]
Products [posts_product]
Brands [terms_product_brand]
Product Categories [terms_product_cat]
Full Code [terms_pa_full-code]
```

The first 6 all return results as expected but Full Code [terms_pa_full-code], although indexed returns no results. However, there should be several 100 if not 1000 as if a product has a Full Code it is set to be 'Visible on the product page'.

Because it's showing as something that can be indexed I'm assuming we don't need to do any custom coding so not sure why it wouldn't display any results?

Has anyone experienced anything similar

Answer (score 0):

The `terms_pa_full-code` does only contain some metadata, not the values which are them correctly pushed as part of the product data if everything goes well.

You can then use values of that taxonomy as a facet to display a list of available options given a user search query.

You can also register for the Algolia plugin for WooCommerce here: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/#woocommerce and get this setup for you in a few clicks.

Comment: Hi, I posted the same question on https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/#woocommerce but unfortunately didn't get an answer there either.